# Install Perl 6 modules in non standard location

Tags: perl-module, raku, rakudo-star

Installing Perl 6 using the Rakudo Star 2016.01 production is quite straighforward. I did the manual installation as suggested [here](http://rakudo.org/how-to-get-rakudo/#Installing-Rakudo-Star-Source):

```
perl Configure.pl --backend=moar --gen-moar --prefix=/opt/rakudo/rakudo-star-2016.01
make
make install
```

Perl6 is now installed on `/opt/rakudo/rakudo-star-2016.01/bin`

Panda, a Perl 6 module manager that comes along with Rakudo, is installed in `/opt/rakudo/rakudo-star-2016.01/share/perl6/site/bin`

I can then add both paths to the $PATH variable to have a running installation of Perl6 right away.

My only problem is that the default installation for Perl 6 modules is still in the $HOME directory: `~/.perl6`

However, I would like to have Perl 6 modules installed in `/opt` as well, actually in `/opt/perl/perl6`

I tried to set PERL6LIB variable, before running the installation steps above, with
`export PERL6LIB=/opt/perl/perl6`
but without any success, because modules are still installed `~/.perl6`

How can I tell Perl6 or Panda to install modules in a non-standard location, outside my $HOME directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting PERL6LIB should suffice to specify the path where new Perl 6 modules will be installed. This variable can be set prior to Perl 6 installation.

```
export PERL6LIB="/opt/perl/perl6/lib" # or better is to put this line in .profile or .bash_profile
perl Configure.pl --backend=moar --gen-moar --prefix=/opt/rakudo-star/rakudo-star-2016.01
make && make install
```

This will install perl6 in `/opt/rakudo-star/rakudo-star-2016.01/bin` and panda in `/opt/rakudo-star/rakudo-star-2016.01/share/perl6/site/bin`

New modules can be installed with panda, e.g.

```
panda install Task::Star
```

and they should be found in `/opt/perl/perl6/lib/.precomp` (it's a hidden folder...)

During this installation `~/.perl6` is still created but should be empty.